# How to change font for a particular UI (QML) when the language is either Korean or Chinese?

Tags: c++, qt, qml, qt5

I have the following QML document (reduced for simplicity) -

```
Item {
   Label { // Label1
      text: qsTr("Label1")
   }

   Label { //Label2
      text: qsTr("Label2")
   }
}
```

I have a C++ class that searches for the translation QM files and call installTranslator when the application language is changed by the user. Translation is working properly.

The requirement is that I need to change the font of `Label1` if the current language is Korean or Chinese but the font of `Label2` should not change. If the language is not one of those two, the font for both `Label1` and `Label2` should be same.

Can you please tell me how can I detect if the current language is Korean or Chinese and how can we get a signal that the language has been changed when that happens?

Comment: A small correction for your subject line. Please use "Chinese" instead of "Mandarin". You had it correct in the description body.

Comment: How do you detect, in the first place, that the application language has been changed? And why won't you use it?

Comment: Anyway, check [`Window.window.locale.name`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-controls2-applicationwindow.html#locale-prop) or [`Qt.locale().name`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qml-qtqml-locale.html#name-prop).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can solve this with `qsTr()`.

For instance, we can introduce `qsTr("western")` which, by default, is `"western"`. For Chinese, (Japanese) and Korean you can use Linguist to change `qsTr("western")` to, say, `"cjk"`. Then we can use this to help switch between a default `font.family` versus an asian font family for just Label1 and not Label2.

```
   Label { // Label1
       text: qsTr("Label1")
       property TextMetrics tm: TextMetrics { }
       font.family: qsTr("western") === "western" ? tm.font.family : "some-cjk-font-family"
   }
   Label { //Label2
       text: qsTr("Label2")
   }
```

If you wish to apply this logic in multiple places you can refactor some properties that you can bind to:

```
    property string cjkCheck: qsTr("western") // "western" (default) or "cjk" (Chinese, Japanese, or Korean)
    property bool isCJK: cjkCheck !== "western"
    property TextMetrics tm: TextMetrics { }
    property string cjkFontFamily: isCJK ? "some-cjk-font-family" : tm.font.family

    Label { // Label1
        text: qsTr("Label1")
        font.family: cjkFontFamily
    }
    Label { //Label2
        text: qsTr("Label2")
    }
```

[EDIT]

Based on your more recent comment, another solution is you can have a LocalizedLabel, e.g.

```
// LocalizedLabel.qml
import QtQuick
import QtQuick.Controls
Label {
    font.family: qsTr("Arial")
}
```

Then, you can use the `LocalizedLabel` when you need it. That means, you get to default to "Arial" or choose a specific font-family and have it all managed by (1) a reusable LocalizedLabel component, (2) manage the font-family via Linguist.

```
    LocalizedLabel { // Label1
        text: qsTr("Label1")
    }
    Label { //Label2
        text: qsTr("Label2")
    }
```

Comment: This is very clever but the problem is the application supports whole set of languages like Hindi, Russian and this will not work in those cases

Comment: I've edited the answer to show setting the font-family via Linguist directly.

Comment: Qt uses this concept with QT_LAYOUT_DIRECTION so that you can fine-tune RTL control via Linguist which is similar to your font problem. https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qtquick-positioning-righttoleft.html